# iOS 8 data sharing between users

Tags: ios, ios8, data-sharing

I'm new to iOS. I need to create a small app that allows registered users to share particular data between them and I'm looking for the best solution. I know I could create a server, which handle user authentication, pushing notifications and sharing data between them, but maybe there is a simpler and better way. I saw iOS 8 introduced CloudKit, but I haven't a chance to test it. Do you think it could meet my expectations?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look into [Parse](https://parse.com/) or other same services.

CloudKit on the other hand also has capabilities that you are looking for. But this would not be available in versions below iOS 8

> CloudKit provides you with Authentication, private and public database, structured and asset storage services - all for free with very high limits.

[CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/cloudkit-storage/)